# How to Create a Folder From FileName in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have files like

```
ABCD_12234.csv
ABCD_56789.csv
CDE_EFG_123456.csv
CDE_EFG_786542.csv
```

I want to make folder names like ABCD files will go under ABCD folder
CDE_EFG files will go under CDE_EFG folder

Comment: where you will create the folder ? you can use functions like @split, refer this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/414558/extract-date-from-filename-in-copy-activity-adf.html)

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a Folder from Filename in ADF. Please follow these steps:

**Step 1:**

- First Create a pipeline with `Get Metadata` and add `child items`

[image]

- Create a variable. In my scenario `val1` taken as a variable

[image]

**Step2:**

- Connect **Get Metadata** with **For each Activity** and add dynamic content of child item: `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`

[image]

> **Inside forEach**

- Go to set variable add this dynamic content: `@substring(item().name ,0, lastindexof(item().name,'_'))` Using this dynamic expression you will get single file. So, Use set variable with copy activity.

[image]

Go to Source of copy activity -> Open dataset -> Create Parameter ->Go to connection and add dynamic content of file: `@dataset().file_name`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Go to sink dataset -> Create two parameters one for folder and another for file In my scenario `folder1` and `file12` as parameters.

[image]

- add dynamic content for Folder: `@dataset().folder1` and file: `@dataset().file12` in connection
  [image]
- Then go to sink ->  add dynamic content for Folder: `@variables('val1')` and file: `@item().name`

[image]

The pipeline run is successful. It writes a file and folder with the required name. Look at the following image for reference.

[image]

[image]